# Connection error trying to connect Postgresql with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, connection

I'm trying to connect my app in rails with Postgresql, but I'm having an error about username, but, I've checked several times and everything seems to be ok.
I'm using rails 7
This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres:14-alpine"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=aventuraweb
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=aventuraweb_development
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_development:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: "redis:7"
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

volumes:
  postgres_data_development: {}
```

And this the database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: aventuraweb_development
  username: aventuraweb
  password: secret
  host: localhost
```

I run foreman and everything seems to be ok, but when I try to reach the page, I found the error:

```
aventuraweb-database-1  | 2023-07-16 17:40:16.711 UTC [29] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "aventuraweb"
19:40:16 db.1    | aventuraweb-database-1  | 2023-07-16 17:40:16.711 UTC [29] DETAIL:  Role "aventuraweb" does not exist.
19:40:16 db.1    | aventuraweb-database-1  |    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"

18:21:12 web.1   | ActiveRecord::DatabaseConnectionError (There is an issue connecting to your database with your username/password, username: aventuraweb.
18:21:12 web.1   | 
18:21:12 web.1   | Please check your database configuration to ensure the username/password are valid.
```

I tried to prune system and network several times, but I don't know what to do next
Any clue what is happening?
Thanks!